# No persistent command history in Python 3.5 (virtualenv)

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I recently set up a new virtualenv for Python 3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04 and whenever I enter a python shell in the terminal (by typing "python3") I have no persistent history of commands I entered in the terminal previously.

On the regular system python3, persistent command history works fine and required no special setup. How can I enable it for the virtualenv?

Comment: Is your virtualenv *not* using the system python3? Did you install a separate Python version? If so, how did you do that? It sounds like you may be missing `readline`; the best way to fix that depends on how you set things up in the first place.

Comment: If I activate the virtualenv and type "which python3" it shows me $virtualenvpath/bin/python3. However, I didn't install a separate Python version. To set up the virtualenv I typed "virtualenv --system-site-packages -p python3 $virtualenvpath" (from the Tensorflow install instructions: https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_linux#InstallingVirtualenv)

Also, everything else about the virtualenv works fine. I also verified that readline is installed in the virtualenv.

Comment: Strange. What happens if you do `import readline` in your virtualenv? What about `import site`; does that affect anything?

Comment: Neither import raises an error or affects anything

Comment: That sounds like either you're not actually on Python 3, or something is preventing the normal operation of the `site` module. There are several command-line options that would cause this, or it could be some part of tensorflow I'm not aware of, or a file named `site.py` or a package named `site` could be interfering with things.

Comment: I'm definitely in python3. Like I said, everything else works perfectly fine, I just can't recall commands from previous python3 shells.

To clarify, I do have command history within the shell, but it clears when I terminate the shell.

Comment: Also, I can import the site module and verify that it's the correct one

Comment: "To clarify, I do have command history within the shell" - that would have been useful to know earlier. Now that I know that, I can see the parts of your post where you tried to say it, but it wasn't clear at all.

Comment: Apparently virtualenv uses its own custom site.py, which hasn't stayed in sync very well with changes in the "regular" site.py. This seems to be one of the incompatibilities. You may need to configure the readline history file yourself.

Comment: I found, as you said, I needed to configure it manually. Ironically, I found the answer in a question on how to disable this (but I changed the history length to be non-zero): https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121390 I can confirm that this works

Comment: It would be preferable to find a general solution though - this one doesn't scale as I have to tell all the users of the virtualenv to make a .pythonrc file in their home directory that sets up the history and then add "export PYTHONSTARTUP=~/.pythonrc" to their .bashrc or .profile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the answer is hidden in the comments and therefore hard to find:

From https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/121390 from @Jason's comment:

Create a `.pythonrc.py` file:

```
import os
import atexit
import readline

readline_history_file = os.path.join(
    os.path.expanduser('~'),
    '.python_history'
)
try:
    readline.read_history_file(readline_history_file)
except IOError:
    pass

atexit.register(readline.write_history_file, readline_history_file)
```

and export it by adding the following line to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PYTHONSTARTUP=$HOME/.pythonrc.py
```